# flex item doesn't stay inside parent when available space changes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a flex container (A) with two or more flex items arranged in a column.  The top flex item (B) is a Bootstrap Collapse panel.  The bottom the bottom flex item (C) has two divs (D and E) placed horizontally.  When the collapse panel (B) expands, the bottom (C) should shrink to remain in the container (A), forcing the two children (D and E) to shrink, making use of `overflow-y:scroll;` if their content is too large, but it doesn't work. Instead, C extends downward beyond the bottom of A.  If I apply `overflow-y:scroll;` to C, it works, but I end up with a useless scroll bar on the right side of C.

Here is a diagram:

```
+------------------------+
| A: Flex Container      |
| +--------------------+ |
| | B: Collapse Panel  | |
| +--------------------+ |
| +--------------------+ |
| |  C: Bottom item    | |
| | +-------+ +------+ | |
| | | D     | |  E   | | |
| | +-------+ +------+ | |
| +--------------------+ |
+------------------------+
```

My code is on codepen at http://codepen.io/pdebarros/pen/jWGKrE
Here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 260px; border: 10px solid red;">
    <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel (section B)</a>
        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: yellow; height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
      <div style="width:40%; background-color: lightgreen; overflow-y: scroll; ">
        Section D
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div style="width:50%; background-color: pink; overflow-y: scroll;">Section E</div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I know there are many other questions on related issues, but I couldn't find one that addresses this particular issue.  And as often happens, in the process of writing the question, I discovered the answer.  I will put it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to apply `overflow-y: hidden;` to the bottom item (C).  Apparently, vertically clipping a div that has `overflow-y:scroll` causes the scroll bar to activate.

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 260px; border: 10px solid red;">
    <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel (section B)</a>
        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: yellow; height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row; overflow-y:hidden;">
      <div style="width:40%; background-color: lightgreen; overflow-y: scroll; ">
        Section D
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>1</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div style="width:50%; background-color: pink; overflow-y: scroll;">Section E</div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```